# How to send data from backend Springboot to client frontend without the use of a Controller?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, tomcat

The overview of the project is this:

1. Upload file to Springboot server via an endpoint
2. The endpoint sends an `OK` response when the file is received, but continues to process the file in the background, running tests on the file.

So, since the endpoint of the controller has already returned a response, how can I send info from the backend to the frontend outside of using the Controller.

**Here is what is running after the Controller returns the response:**

```
     CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            int count = 0;
            boolean stillProcessing = true;
            while (stillProcessing) {
                stillProcessing = !test.isTestComplete();
                if (test.getNumberOfInstancesComplete() > count) {
                    count = test.getNumberOfInstancesComplete();
                    log.info("{}/{} instances completed so far", count, test.getInstances().size());
                }
            }
        });
```

The `log.info` line is what I need to return to the frontend React side of things.

The end goal is to basically have a loading bar shown to users using the values printed in `log.info()`.

Comment: You can use websockets to send the uploaded file info once the scan is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use websockets to notify frontend without a controller. Here is the example code to send a message to the client from backend using STOMP at any time.

```
@Component
public class PushMessage {

  @Autowired
  SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;


  public <T> void invokeWebSocketEndpoint(String endpoint, T payload) {
    this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(endpoint, payload);
  }

}
```

For more info on STOMP websockets, check out this link
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

If you do not want bi-directional communication between the client and the server and just want to push messages to client from the server you can also make use of Server sent events. Here's a simple example.

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/test")
  public SseEmitter test() {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.execute(() -> {
      try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 10 www.google.com");
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
          String line;
          while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            emitter.send(line);
          }
          emitter.complete();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        emitter.completeWithError(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
    executorService.shutdown();
    return emitter;
  }
```

For more information on Server sent events see this
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events

You can consume server sent events from your frontend using the EventSource API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource